# Python CLR Module with C# DLLs - AddReference works, import doesn't

Tags: python, .net, pycharm, clr, python.net

This question is related to sensible data that I cannot share, but the question is pretty simple. I'm working on PyCharm 2017.1.2, python 2.7.13.

I have a file in a specific format (kind of an encrypted XML, unparsable), that needs to be converted into Excel to modify some values and then export it back to this original format. For some security reasons, I just cannot go around this conversion. All good, I have an Excel add-in that I can use for this, inside two C# DLLs, that does 'import' into the Excel format and 'export' it back to the weird XML.

I cannot use IronPython either because the software I'm designing uses library IronPython just can't manage, so I'm stuck with good old Python 2.7.

I'm currently using the clr module from pythonnet to import the DLLs into my software. The import code (not sensible) looks like this :

```
import clr
import sys

sys.path.append('C:/My/Path/To/The/DLLs/Folder')
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c')
clr.AddReference('My.ClassLib.DLL')
clr.AddReference('My.ExcelImportExport.DLL')

import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as Excel
try:
    from My.ClassLib.DLL import XMLParser
    import My.ExcelImportExport.DLL
    from My.ExcelImportExport.DLL import DeviceSettingsUtility
except Exception, e:
    print unicode(e)
```

Both DLLs I'm working with are located in the same folder. CLR has no problem adding the DLLs reference.

What is weird : everything works fine with the `'My.ClassLib.DLL'` : I can access its classes and methods without any issues.
But as soon as I try `import My.ExcelImportExport.DLL` or the line after, I've got an `ImportError: No module named My.ExcelImportExport.DLL`. When, after adding reference with clr, I list all the assemblies, I see both `My.ClassLib.DLL` and `My.ExcelImportExport.DLL`, so the problem doesn't come from here. The problem as to come from the `My.ExcelImportExport.DLL`.

I've looked both DLLs with a decompiler and haven't found anything that makes the ClassLib.DLL work and would explain why the other one doesn't.

Finally, my question : What needs to be in the DLL (C# code) for clr to be able to import it?

Comment: Please checkout this wiki page: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows-and-Linux

Comment: Is your .NET class actually named "DLL"? Normally, after adding the reference to the DLL, instead of `from My.ExcelImportExport.DLL import DeviceSettingsUtility`, I would expect to see something like `from My.ExcelImportExport import DeviceSettingsUtility`.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.
The pythonnet/wiki page doesn't seem to help.
One more note:
clr.__dict__ or help(clr) list some modules that work correctly, but clr.ListAssemblies lists a much larger number of assemblies, including the one I have that I can't get working. It seems that a lot of assemblies can be loaded by clr, but not used as modules in Python. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You must try to use the latest version of pythonnet which you can get from github using the link https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Installation

I believe this would work as I am using python version 3.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Pythonnet uses NAMESPACES as modules. Not classes or anything. And they are SUB-MODULES of `clr`.

```
import clr
clr.System.Console.WriteLine("foo.bar.baz")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it may depend on .NET framework version.

On this condition:

- Python 3.8.10
- pythonnet 2.5.2

Target framework of class library:

- .NET Standard 1.0, 1.6, 2.0: Work fine
- .NET Standard 2.1: Failed

Tested with calculation DLL example:
https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/How-to-call-a-dynamic-library